# how to dynamically create a div in angular having a certain class?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a div on click of a button:

the div should be like this:

```
<div class="my-blur"><div>
```

I am doing this:

```
$scope.showFloatingActioButtons = function() {
        var newEle = angular.element('<div class="my-blur"></div>');
        $compile(newEle)($scope);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there... you just need to add that element to the DOM somehwere.

```
angular.element('someselector-or-dom-element').append(newEle);
```

And unless you have bindings or directives on your new element, there is no reason to compile it.

I've added a running example to help clear up any confusion.

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', []);

function MyCtrl(){}
MyCtrl.prototype = {
  addElement:function(){
    var newEle = angular.element("<div class='red'></div>");
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    angular.element(target).append(newEle);
  }
};

app.controller('myCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

```css
.red{
  margin: 10px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.addElement()">Add Element</button>
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: getting `newEle.appendTo is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, only available if you have jQuery... let me fix the anwer.

Comment: but i don't have jquery.

Comment: @lakshay - Updated the answer to take into account that you don't have jQuery.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is your selector correct?

Comment: `var newEle = angular.element('<div class="my-blur"></div>');
            angular.element(document.getElementById('search-button')).append(newEle);`

Comment: hi josh can you please one help me.??

Comment: @coderwill - Anything in particular you need help with?

Comment: hi josh i have create one div in form tag and div is store textbox,dropdown,like this store now open modal popup 1st time div is show then i click add button i want to same div append smae process like click on button like 4 time then want to same div 4 time in angularjs so how can do that any idea??

Comment: thanks for the great explanation and example..but I want to add some dynamic id and also want to add value to them like. first dive has id=1 and name as <p> manish</p> and another have different name and id. so how do I achieve that ?

Comment: @Manish - It sound like you might really be wanting to do data binding as well. If you have a list of things you are adding into the DOM, then you are probably better of using an `ng-repeat` and normal data binding.

Obviously you can do it this way as well, but you lose the benefits of AngularJS at that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Josh, I have used ng-repeat yesterday and fix my problem. Thanks for your feedback will ping you if face any issue with angular. :D