# How to append div dynamically lower part of div tag?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add div dynamically lower part of a div like chat box in Facebook or whats-app. Whenever I want to add dives it add from upper part of the body.

Comment: These might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147303/how-can-i-send-an-inner-div-to-the-bottom-of-its-parent-div

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764815/how-to-dynamically-create-a-div-in-angular-having-a-certain-class

Answer (score 1):

This might help!.. for your dynamically add divs and for chat like css, you'll need to modify your css.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

function MyCtrl(){}
MyCtrl.prototype = {
  addElement:function(){
    var newEle = angular.element("<div class='red'>new div!</div>");
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    angular.element(target).append(newEle);
  }
};

app.controller('myCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.addElement()">Add Element</button>
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```